# What does "that guy" refer to?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, the-suicide-squad-2021

In *The Suicide Squad* (2021), Bloodsport and his team visit a bar. A lady bartender
brought them drinks:

> Bloodsport: Just one.
>
> Peacemaker: You're gonna be **that guy**?
>
> Bloodsport: I'm gonna be **that guy**.

What does "that guy" refer to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"[That guy](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=That%20Guy&page=2)", in this case, is referring to Bloodsport being a particular stereotype, in this case a "killjoy", someone who puts duty in front of fun, and therefore is not joining in the excessive drinking.

There isn't one particular stereotype associated with the usage, of course, so it has to be determined by context.